# wordpress: is there a way to hook into action/filter call

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, wordpress

Okay. Here's what I'm trying to get:

I'm about to create a very simple logging plugin.
Every time an action or filter is fired - I need to log it to the file.
The idea is that we will be able to see exactly which actions and filters are executed (and function they run) for every page load. This includes the order that they run in.

Thanks!

Comment: IMO, here at [so], this Q is off-topic ("Questions *asking for code* must show the minimal understanding of the problem being solved"). In other hand, would be perfectly fit at [wordpress.se]. You can go one step further researching the tag [`<plugin-development>`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-development?sort=votes&pageSize=50) over there. Am not locating it, but there are examples on how to dump all this info (with the `all` hook, if not mistaken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As brasofilo mentioned there is an "all" hook, you can use it like this:

```
add_action('all', 'log_hook_function');

function log_hook_function( $parameters ) {
    // Dump out $parameters to see what you're working with
}
```